# Lazy Load listview Item from server json response

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, listview

I'm developing an android app which load data from server by a json parser.I want to load data in a 10 item part from server and when the user scroll down the listview new 10 item part load from server and add to current listview(such as market apps).

here is the java code:

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {
    //jpcode
    int part=0;
    String refreshNumber="0";
    //convert to shamsi
    Roozh jCal = new Roozh();

    String myjpdiff;
    ImageButton btnNewProduct; 
    View ntCheck;
    private SessionManager session;
    private Button logout;
    //internet check jp
    // flag for Internet connection status
        Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

        // Connection detector class
        ConnectionDetector cd;

        //end internet check jp
        private SQLiteHandler db; //jpcode
    //end jpcode

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://www.jpdesign.ir/android_login_api/ac/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    //jpcode
    private static final String TAG_AUTH = "auth";
    private static final String TAG_HIT = "hit";
    private static final String TAG_DATE = "created_at";
    private static final String TAG_JPTIME = "jptime";
    private static final String TAG_JPPart = "part";
    private TextView txtName;
    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;
    Typeface   jpfont;

    public PullToRefreshListView listView;  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_right_in,R.anim.push_right_out);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);


           jpfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/yekan.ttf");
          TextView fakeDate= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          fakeDate.setTypeface(jpfont);


        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());    //jpcode

        //adding slidemenu
        final SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.slide_layout);
        ImageButton iconfehrest = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sliding);
// get name of user
        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        String name = user.get("name");
        String email = user.get("email");
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mnt);
        // Displaying the user details on the screen
        Log.d("LOG", name +" and "+email);
        txtName.setText(name);
        //txtEmail.setText(email);


///end get name
        iconfehrest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                menu.toggle();
            }
        });


        //end slide menu



//jpcode
        logout= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Ulogout);
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logoutUser();
            }
        });
        final View ntCheck = findViewById(R.id.net_check);
        ntCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // creating connection detector class instance
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // get Internet status
        isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
      ImageButton ntchecker= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nt_check);

      ntchecker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(AllProductsActivity.this,AllProductsActivity.class);    
            startActivity(i);
            } 

    });

    //jp pull to refresh
      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder() .detectAll().penaltyLog().build(); 
      StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            listView = (PullToRefreshListView) getListView();
            listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
                //@Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    // Do work to refresh the list here.
                    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    // Loading products in Background Thread
                    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
                    pDialog.hide();

                }
            });


            // end of jp pull to refresh


        // check for Internet status
        if (isInternetPresent) {
            // Internet Connection is Present
            // make HTTP requests
            // Hashmap for ListView
            productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            ntCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide internet checker
            // Loading products in Background Thread
            new LoadAllProducts().execute();
        } else {
            // Internet connection is not present
            // Ask user to connect to Internet
            Log.d("No Internet Connection", "You don't have internet connection.");
            //Toast.makeText(this, "You don't have internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ntCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        btnNewProduct = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.newpost);
        ImageButton searchBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.SearchBtn);

        btnNewProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching create new product activity
                Intent i = new Intent(AllProductsActivity.this, NewProductActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        //end of jp
        // Hashmap for ListView
        //jpdast productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        //jpdast new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();



        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ViewPro.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });


        //jp scroller

                //add the footer before adding the adapter, else the footer will not load!
//              View footerView = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer, null, false);
//              this.getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
                //Here is where the magic happens
                lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME,TAG_AUTH,TAG_HIT, TAG_DATE},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.auth, R.id.hit, R.id.date }

                            );
                    @Override
                    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                                int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                                int lastItemPosition=adapter.getCount();
                        if ( adapter.getCount() >= 10 && lastItem  > adapter.getCount() - 6) {
                            boolean isLoading = false;
                            if (!isLoading) {
                                if(isInternetPresent){
                                    if(lastItem > lastItemPosition){
                                        //productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                                        // Loading products in Background Thread
                                        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
                                        //receivedData();
                                        Log.d("LOG", "jpdesign is here");
                                        ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        part += 1;
                                        }
                                    }
                            isLoading = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

                    });

                //jp end scroller


    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received 
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("در حال دریافت اطلاعات ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


             Log.d("LOG", part+"");
             List<NameValuePair> params2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_JPPart, "" + part));

            JSONObject json2 = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "POST", params2);

            Log.d("post checker: ", json2.toString());

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);


            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            //Log.d("jpdesign All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1 ) {
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    refreshNumber="1";
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json2.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                    String myjpdate=json.getString(TAG_JPTIME);
                     // Log.d("TIME TEST", myjpdate);
                      Log.d("TIME TEST", products+"");
                    // looping through All Products
                //for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                      for (int i =  0; i < products.length(); i++) {    
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        //jpcode
                        String auth = c.getString(TAG_AUTH);
                        String hit = c.getString(TAG_HIT);
                        String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

                       //jptime diff
                        String dateStart = date;
                        String dateStop = myjpdate;

                            Date d1 = null;
                            Date d2 = null;
                            Date jd1 = null;
                            Date jd2 = null;

                            Date fyear = null;


                            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                            SimpleDateFormat jpformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");






                            try {
                                d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
                                d2 = format.parse(dateStop);
                                jd1 =jpformat.parse(dateStart);
                                jd2 =jpformat.parse(dateStop);

                                DateFormat formatter ; 

                                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                fyear = (Date)formatter.parse(dateStart); 


                                // (3) create a new String using the date format we want
                                String YMD = formatter.format(fyear);

                                int len=YMD.length();
                                String[] myInArray=new String[len];

                                   String FY=String.valueOf(YMD.charAt(0))+String.valueOf(YMD.charAt(1))+String.valueOf(YMD.charAt(2))+String.valueOf(YMD.charAt(3));
                                   String FM=String.valueOf(YMD.charAt(5))+String.valueOf(YMD.charAt(6));
                                   String FD=String.valueOf(YMD.charAt(8))+String.valueOf(YMD.charAt(9));

                                jCal.GregorianToPersian(Integer.parseInt(FY), Integer.parseInt(FM), Integer.parseInt(FD));
                                String myconverttime= jCal.toString();
                                //in milliseconds
                                long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
                                long jpdiff = jd2.getTime() - jd1.getTime();


                                long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
                                long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
                                long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
                                long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
 // 1s=1000 ,1m=60000,1h=3.6e+6 1day = 86400000


                            if(jpdiff==0 && diff<=60000){  myjpdiff="هم اکنون";}
                            if(jpdiff==0 && diff>60000 && diff<(59*60000)){  myjpdiff=diffMinutes+" دقیقه قبل";}
                            if(jpdiff==0 && diff>(60*60000) && diff<(24*59*60000)){  myjpdiff=diffHours+" ساعت قبل";}
                            if(jpdiff==86400000){  myjpdiff="   1 روز قبل   ";}
                            if(jpdiff>86400000){  myjpdiff=myconverttime;}


                            Log.d("TIME TEST",FY+"   "+diff+"   "+ jpdiff+"    "+diffDays+"day "+diffHours+"hour "+diffMinutes+"");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        //end jptime diff
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_AUTH, auth); //jpcode 
                        map.put(TAG_HIT, hit); //jpcode
                        map.put(TAG_DATE, myjpdiff); //jpcode
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);


                    }



                } else {
                    refreshNumber="0";
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     **/

//                  TextView dt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
//                  dt.setTypeface(jpfont);
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME,TAG_AUTH,TAG_HIT, TAG_DATE},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.auth, R.id.hit, R.id.date }

                            );


                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);


                    ((PullToRefreshListView) getListView()).onRefreshComplete();

                }

            });

        }





    }


    //jpcode logout

    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);

        db.deleteUsers();

        // Launching the login activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(AllProductsActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    //end jp logout
}
```

and here is the php file on the server:

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1

header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 2014 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

?>
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table

//jpadd codes
 $part = $_POST['part'];
 //$part = $_GET['part'];
  $start = $part * 10;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products   ORDER BY`created_at` DESC LIMIT $start, 10") or die(mysql_error());
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products ORDER BY`created_at` DESC") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
 $response["jptime"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 //$jptime["my_date"]= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $response["products"] = array();
 $response["part"] = $part;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        //$product["price"] = $row["price"];
       //$product["description"] = $row["description"];
        $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        //$product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];
        //jpcode
        $product["auth"] = $row["auth"];
        $product["hit"] = $row["hit"];

     // $my_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "محصولی یافت نشد";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

but when the user scroll down the list nothing happen

Comment: First remove adapter code from Scroll method and try to just update list adapter from LoadAllProducts onPostExecute().

Comment: Check out : http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-dynamicaly

Comment: I remove it  but nullexception is happen

Comment: Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
My application code which worked:


public class Product_Listing extends Fragment 
{
private static final String TAG = SubCategoryActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String TAG_IMAGEPATH = "imagepath";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTID = "productid";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";
private static final String TAG_SUPPLIERID = "supplierid";
private static final String TAG_SUPPLIERNAME = "suppliername";
private static final String TAG_CATEGORY_ID = "catid";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT_COUNT = "productcount";

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Products> catList = new ArrayList<Products>();
private ListView listView;
private ProductsAdapter adapter;
int id_count = 0;

private int current_page = 0;
int mPreLast;

public Product_Listing() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product__listing, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list1);
    adapter = new ProductsAdapter(getActivity(), catList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    int currentPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    listView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);

    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
        {
            int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if(lastItem == totalItemCount){
                if (mPreLast != lastItem)
                {
                    mPreLast = lastItem;
                    new LoadProductDesc().execute();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    new LoadProductDesc().execute();
}



private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}

class LoadProductDesc extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            // make a HTTP request

            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet());
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else {
                // close connection
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Test", "Couldn't make a successful request!");
        }
        return responseString;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(final String response) {

        super.onPostExecute(response);
        // Creating volley request obj
        String s1 = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("index");
        current_page += 1;
        final String url = "Your URL Link" + s1 + "," + current_page;

                JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                                try
                                {
                                    if (isNetworkStatusAvialable (getActivity())) {

                                            // Parsing json
                                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length() && response.length() != 0; i++)
                                            {
                                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                                Products products = new Products();
                                                id_count = id_count + 1;
                                                products.setProductName(obj.getString(TAG_PRODUCTNAME));
                                                products.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString(TAG_IMAGEPATH));
                                                products.setProductID(obj.getInt(TAG_PRODUCTID));
                                                products.setSupplierName(obj.getString(TAG_SUPPLIERNAME));
                                                products.setSupplierID(obj.getInt(TAG_SUPPLIERID));
                                                products.setCategoryID(obj.getInt(TAG_CATEGORY_ID));
                                                String count = obj.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_COUNT);

                                                catList.add(products);

                                                TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ListofProducts);
                                                textView.setText(String.valueOf("Total 1 to " + id_count + " Products listed of " + count));
                                            }

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Check Internet Connectivity!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        return;
                                    }

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Check Internet Connectivity!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                hidePDialog();

                                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();
                    }
                });
                // Adding request to request queue
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
            }



}

public static boolean isNetworkStatusAvialable (Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager != null)
    {
        NetworkInfo netInfos = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(netInfos != null)
            if(netInfos.isConnected())
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}


  }
```